# Using Live GPS in QGIS - Speed and quality is not shown

Tags: gps, direction, nmea, speed

I am using QGIS 3.10 together with a ArdusimpleRTK2B Board based on U-Blox ZED F9P processor and a Windows 10 based tablet computer.

Using a SAPOS correction service and having connected it via gpsd the board provides cm-precission **NMEA** Strings **$GNGGA** and **$GNRMC**.
The position of the cursor in the map exactly shows the position of the antenna.

But I wonder, why QGIS does not show values for speed, direction, quality,... in the GPS-Information Box?
What kind of NMEA-data does QGIS expect to show those properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to the other post, Nyall Dawson and others have been making massive changes to the GPS handling in QGIS. I don't see $GPVTG, which looks like the NMEA message you need for speed.

This Pull Request should give you what you need for constellation/satellite quality.

These PRs have been merged into master, but I don't see a milestone for their release. I'm guessing for 3.12, but I don't have a way to confirm for sure.

**GPS - add support for additional messages #33239**
https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/33239

```
Adds support for some additional NMEA message handling to the GPS tools, fixes some issues
[gps] Support GNGGA nmea messages  
[gps] Support GNGSA messages  
[gps] Support GNGSV messages  
[gps] Add support for GPHDT heading from true north messages
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Thus I will wait for the release of QGIS 3.12 and then activate GSA and GSV, too.