# QGIS Live GPS - turn the map according to the direction I move

Tags: qgis, gps, mapping, direction, heading

Using Live GPS in QGIS I would like the map to be rotated automatically, that the direction I am moving to is always upside like in a car navigation sytem.

How can I configurate that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is coming in an upcoming release of QGIS, most likely 3.12.0 at the end of the month.

A number of other GPS improvements will be implemented at the same time.

**Add option to auto-rotate canvas to GPS bearing, show GPS bearing as a line over map #3324**
https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/33240

```
Add option to auto-rotate canvas to GPS bearing:
When enabled, the map canvas will automatically rotate so that it's oriented in the same direction as the GPS bearing
Show GPS bearing as a line over map:
Allow showings a bearing line from the GPS location pointed in the GPS's direction. Allows users to view a "current path" directional line as they navigate using a GPS
```

Comment: Maybe, you can also help me with my first question, which NMEA-Strings are necessary to display speed, direction and qualitiy of signal of the gps receiver. (Question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/350018/using-live-gps-in-qgis-speed-and-quality-is-not-shown )

Comment: Sorry that I did not answer earlier. But that auto-rotate feature within QGIS 3.12 is a great help for me!